# About topological neighborhoods

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory, filters

> An element $p$ of a topological space $(X, \tau)$ lies in the closure of a subset $A$ of $X$ iff there is a filter $\Lambda$ on $X$ such that $A \in \Lambda$ and $\Lambda$ converges to $p.$

Proof:

Let $\mathcal N(p)$ stand for the set of neighborhoods of $p$.

> (i) Suppose $p \in \overline A$. Then $\Lambda = \{F \subseteq X: \exists N \in \mathcal N(p) \text{ with } A \cap N \subseteq F\}$ is a filter on $X, \ \mathcal N(p) \subseteq \Lambda, \ A \in \Lambda$.

> (ii)  Suppose there is a filter $\Lambda$ as described. Then for all $N \in \mathcal N(p), N \cap A \in \Lambda$ and so $N \cap A \neq \varnothing$. Therefore $p \in \overline A$.

My questions:

Regarding (i)

$1.$ Suppose $N \in \mathcal N(p)$. Then since $N \subseteq X$ and because we can always find $N_0$ s.t. $N_0 \cap A \subseteq N$, we have $N \in \Lambda.$ How do we know $N_0$ exists? Does $N_0 = \{p\}$ always work?

$2.$ Since $A \subseteq X$, then by definition $A \in \Lambda$? Correct?

$3.$ Where in the proof do we use the assumption $p \in \overline A?$

Regrading (ii)

$1.$ We have $N, A \subseteq X$ and so by definition $N, A \in \Lambda$. Since $\Lambda$ is closed under $\cap$, it follows $N \cap A \in \Lambda.$ Correct?

$2$. By definition of filters, $\varnothing \not \in \Lambda$ meaning $N \cap A \neq \varnothing$. Correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As to (i): if $N \in \mathcal{N}(p)$, we note that $N \cap A \subseteq N$ and that shows that $N \in \Lambda$.

So in short: to witness $F=N \in \Lambda$ take that same $N$ (no creativity required).

Yes, $N=X$ is enough to witness that $A \in \Lambda$.

We use the assumption $p \in \overline{A}$ to ensure $\Lambda$ does not contain $\emptyset$ (which in my book is part of the definition of a filter, though opinions here differ on that). Recall that a point $p$ is in the closure of $A$ iff *every* neighbourhood of $p$ intersects $A$ in a non-empty set, so that $A \cap N$ in the definition is always non-empty and a fortiori all $F \in \Lambda$ as well.

You're right about (ii): we apply the same closure criterion as before and use that $\Lambda$ is not allowed to contain $\emptyset$.

Comment: How do we know $N \cap A \subseteq N$? Also, how does $A \cap N \neq \varnothing \implies F \neq \varnothing$? Suppose $p \in N \cap A.$ Then $p \in N$ and $p \in A.$ But $p \in A \implies p \in N$ as $A \subseteq X$ and we can take $N$ to be $X$? For the latter: $A \cap N \ne \varnothing \implies A \ne \varnothing.$ Since $F \in \Lambda$, then $F \subseteq X$. We are given $A \subseteq X$ and so $F = A \ne \varnothing$? Make sense?

Comment: @user938299 $N \cap A \subseteq N$ is trivial set theory. $p \in N \cap A$ implies $p \in N$ and we're done! Also if $N \cap A \neq \emptyset$ it contains some element $x$ and this same $x$ is *also* in $F$ so $F \neq \emptyset$, so that's also trivial.

Comment: I am like a calculus student who struggles with elementary algebra. I get the the main points of theorems, but get mired in elementary set manipulations part. Working on that :)